# getter is returning null in my flutter code using box

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-hive

this is my main.dart
is there anything wrong with my code as my getter is throwing a null in terminal and screen is stucked

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  BlocSupervisor.delegate = SimpleBlocDelegate();
  final document = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  Hive.init(document.path);
  Hive.registerAdapter(GetConfigModelAdapter());
  Hive.registerAdapter(AppConfigAdapter());
  Hive.registerAdapter(AdsConfigAdapter());
  Hive.registerAdapter(AuthUserAdapter());
  await Hive.openBox<GetConfigModel>('getConfigbox');
  await Hive.openBox<AppConfig>('appConfigbox');
  await Hive.openBox<AdsConfig>('adsConfigbox');
  await Hive.openBox<AuthUser>('user');
  await Hive.openBox('seenBox');
  GetConfigModel getConfigModel;
  getConfigModel = await Repository().getAppConfig();
  GetConfigService().updateGetConfig(getConfigModel);
  Admob.initialize();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

String getAppId(AdsConfig adsConfig) {
  if (Platform.isIOS) {
    print(adsConfig.admobAppId);
    return adsConfig.admobAppId;
  } else if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    return adsConfig.admobAppId;
  }
  return null;
}
```

`my app.dart file`

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with AfterLayoutMixin {
  GetConfigModel getConfigModel;
  bool isFirstSeen = false;
  String notifyContent;

  @override
  void initState() {
    printLog("_MyAppState initState");
    Future.delayed(
      Duration(seconds: 1),
      () {
        MyConnectivity.instance.initialise();
        MyConnectivity.instance.myStream.listen((onData) {
          printLog("[_MyAppState] internet issue change: $onData");

          if (MyConnectivity.instance.isIssue(onData)) {
            if (MyConnectivity.instance.isShow == false) {
              MyConnectivity.instance.isShow = true;
              showDialogNotInternet(context).then((onValue) {
                MyConnectivity.instance.isShow = false;
                printLog("[showDialogNotInternet] dialog closed $onValue");
              });
            }
          } else {
            if (MyConnectivity.instance.isShow == true) {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
              MyConnectivity.instance.isShow = false;
            }
          }
        });
      },
    );
    super.initState();
    configOneSignal();
  }

  @override
  Future<void> afterFirstLayout(BuildContext context) async {
    printLog("[_MyAppState] afterFirstLayout");
    isFirstSeen = await checkFirstSeen();
    setState(() {});
  }

  Future checkFirstSeen() async {
    var box = Hive.box('seenBox');
    bool _seen = await box.get("isFirstSeen") ?? false;
    if (_seen) {
      return false;
    } else {
      await box.put("isFirstSeen", true);
      return true;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    printLog("MyAppState");
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        Provider<AuthService>(
          create: (context) => AuthService(),
        ),
        Provider<GetConfigService>(
          create: (context) => GetConfigService(),
        ),
      ],
      child: MultiBlocProvider(
        providers: [
          BlocProvider(create: (context) => LoginBloc(Repository())),
          BlocProvider(create: (context) => RegistrationBloc(Repository())),
          BlocProvider(create: (context) => FirebaseAuthBloc(Repository())),
          BlocProvider(
              create: (context) =>
                  PhoneAuthBloc(userRepository: UserRepository())),
        ],
        child: MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          routes: Routes.getRoute(),
          home: RenderFirstScreen(
            isFirstSeen: isFirstSeen,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void configOneSignal() async {
    await OneSignal.shared.init(Config.oneSignalAppID);
    //show notification content
    OneSignal.shared
        .setInFocusDisplayType(OSNotificationDisplayType.notification);
    OneSignal.shared.setNotificationReceivedHandler((notification) {
      //content notification
      setState(() {
        notifyContent =
            notification.jsonRepresentation().replaceAll('\\n', '\n');
      });
    });
  }
}

// ignore: must_be_immutable
class RenderFirstScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  bool isMandatoryLogin = false;
  final bool isFirstSeen;

  RenderFirstScreen({Key key, this.isFirstSeen}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    printLog("RenderFirstScreen");
    return ValueListenableBuilder(
      valueListenable: Hive.box<GetConfigModel>('getConfigbox').listenable(),
      builder: (context, box, widget) {
        isMandatoryLogin = box.get(0).appConfig.mandatoryLogin;
        return renderFirstScreen(isMandatoryLogin);
      },
    );
  }

  Widget renderFirstScreen(bool isMandatoryLogin) {
    print(isMandatoryLogin);
    if (isFirstSeen) {
      return OnBoardScreen(
        isMandatoryLogin: isMandatoryLogin,
      );
    } else if (isMandatoryLogin) {
      return LoginPage();
    } else {
      return MainScreen();
    }
  }
}
```

this is returning me null and my app is just getting stucked on splash screen do anyone know how to resolve this issue i did try downgrading flutter sdk but i am still getting the same problem

Comment: what exactly is retuning null? Please add the line

Answer (score 0):

I think the `error` is in this line

```
bool _seen = await box.get("isFirstSeen") ?? false;
```

and the reason is that you have not putted any value in this key `isFirstSeen` previously but you are trying get it so it's simply returning `null`.

What you can do is put some value on `initStatee` in the key `isFirstSeen` then try to access it. This should solve your issue.

Comment: like how can i do that ? as i tried changing values can you help me out with this ? @diwyansh

Comment: Have you tried the above solution?

Comment: no as i am not able to understand what you refering ! though this this working with flutter 2.2.3

Comment: are you getting error on the same line or any other?

Comment: how can i rewrite ismandatorylogin line ? isMandatoryLogin = box.get(0).appConfig.mandatoryLogin; this line .get(0) not getting value in flutter greater than 2.2.3 and i am using 2.8.1
@diwyansh 
return ValueListenableBuilder(
      valueListenable: Hive.box<GetConfigModel?>('getConfigbox').listenable(),
      builder: (context, dynamic box, widget) {
        isMandatoryLogin = box.get(0).appConfig.mandatoryLogin;
        //isMandatoryLogin = true;
        return renderFirstScreen(isMandatoryLogin);
      },
    );
  }

Comment: https://github.com/adityasinghborana/project2- this is my full source code you can try and run over i do not know if i am doing things right or not